# Why don't select elements in an Infobox expand?

Tags: html, bing-maps

If you create an [infobox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg675208.aspx) with the Bing Maps v7 Ajax control and set the [htmlContent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg675210.aspx) to some html with a select element in it, nothing happens when you click on the drop down arrow on the select.

```
var options = {
    htmlContent: '<div style="width: 200px;border: #727272 1px solid; background: #fff;">' +
        '      Show Range: <select>' +
        '          <option value="default">Default</option>' +
        '          <option value="a">A</option>' +
        '          <option value="b">B</option>' +
        '          <option value="c">C</option>' +
        '      </select>' +
        '</div>'
};
```

jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/bryantlikes/8E2KK/1/

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The main reason is that the generate div that has MicrosoftMap css class applied captures the click event and does not it propagates on the select element.

If you use 'tab' key and then the arrow keys, you can change the values so the select is working fine but the click does not behave in the good way.

I'll try to find a workaround and help you.